# How to connect to remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, linux, remote-access, mysql-error-2003

i have viewed all the related question and answers but still having problem to connect to remote mysql database.

what i have done so far is..

1

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'root'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY  '***' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
```

2

```
my.cnf file in server (which is in /etc/my.cnf path let me if it is not correct)
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

following is the database.yml of my project.

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=[ip of remote server];dbname=dev_db
      username: user
      password: user12
      encoding: utf8
      attributes:
        use_native_enum: true
        default_table_type: INNODB
        default_table_collate: utf8_unicode_ci
        default_table_charset: utf8
```

I am getting following exception

```
PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '50.115.116.203' (4)
```

So what else is missing to configure remote database.

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the correct IP Address?

Comment: yes its correct, i can successfully log in with ssh through that ip.

Comment: Scanning ports on 50.115.116.203

50.115.116.203 isn't responding on port 3306 (mysql).

What port is mysql running on as its not default 3306

Comment: Try using % instead of IP and see if it works. and also FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: are you sure mysql has bound itself to that IP?

Comment: @rinchik plase explain where to use % ? and also are you sure flush privileages will not cause problem to other users rights ?

Comment: @marc B what do you mean by bound ? i didn't understand.

Comment: @Hardik  FLUSH is required to complete the setup and to make the new settings work. It won't affect other users. `ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@‘%'`

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.1.100` This is a local network IP, you have used this IP as the allowed host for your user. However when you connect to this server you are doing so using Public IP Address `50.115.116.203`.
Please check if the server you are connecting from has the same ip as you added for your user as allowed host